# Marking the entire group if condition is true for a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which has Dates and public holidays

```
Date    WeekNum Public_Holiday
1/1/2015    1   1
2/1/2015    1   0
3/1/2015    1   0
4/1/2015    1   0
5/1/2015    1   0
6/1/2015    1   0
7/1/2015    1   0
8/1/2015    2   0
9/1/2015    2   0
10/1/2015   2   0
11/1/2015   2   0
12/1/2015   2   0
13/1/2015   2   0
```

I have to create a conditional column named Public_Holiday_Week, which should return 1, if that particular week has a public holiday

And I want to see an output like this

```
Date    WeekNum Public_Holiday  Public_Holiday_Week
1/1/2015    1   1               1
2/1/2015    1   0               1
3/1/2015    1   0               1
4/1/2015    1   0               1
5/1/2015    1   0               1
6/1/2015    1   0               1
7/1/2015    1   0               1
8/1/2015    2   0               0
9/1/2015    2   0               0
10/1/2015   2   0               0
11/1/2015   2   0               0
12/1/2015   2   0               0
13/1/2015   2   0               0
```

I tried using np.where

```
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = np.where(df['Public_Holiday']==1,1,0)
```

But it applies 0 for other days of the week when it is not a public holiday.

Do I have to apply rolling here? Appreciate your help

Comment: First day of week is `2014-31-12` [link](http://whatweekisit.org/calendar-2015..html)? Why? It is necessary for your data?

Comment: df['weekOfYear'] = df['ActivityDate'].dt.week #week of the year

df['weekNum'] = df.weekOfYear + (df.year % 2015) * 52

Comment: @jezrael This is how I came up with week of the year and week num

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what is a bit weird - weeks by `df['weekOfYear'] = df['ActivityDate'].dt.week` and by column `WeekNum` in sample data are different. And it is reason why was editted my solution - `weeks` column is different like `WeekNum`.

Comment: @jezrael Yes, apologies for not informing that before hand :)

Comment: No, not necessary inform me, only I write this comments if solutions are OK, what you need :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use `resample` and skip the use of the `WeekNum` column altogether.

```
df.assign(
    Public_Holiday_Week=
    df.resample('W-Wed', on='Date').Public_Holiday.transform('max')
)

         Date  WeekNum  Public_Holiday  Public_Holiday_Week
0  2015-01-01        1               1                    1
1  2015-01-02        1               0                    1
2  2015-01-03        1               0                    1
3  2015-01-04        1               0                    1
4  2015-01-05        1               0                    1
5  2015-01-06        1               0                    1
6  2015-01-07        1               0                    1
7  2015-01-08        2               0                    0
8  2015-01-09        2               0                    0
9  2015-01-10        2               0                    0
10 2015-01-11        2               0                    0
11 2015-01-12        2               0                    0
12 2015-01-13        2               0                    0
```

Answer (score 8):

For improve performance dont use `groupby`, rather get all `WeekNum` with at least one `1` and then select values by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), last cast boolean mask to `int`s:

```
weeks = df.loc[df['Public_Holiday'].eq(1), 'WeekNum']
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = df['WeekNum'].isin(weeks).astype(int)

print (df)
         Date  WeekNum  Public_Holiday  Public_Holiday_Week
0    1/1/2015        1               1                    1
1    2/1/2015        1               0                    1
2    3/1/2015        1               0                    1
3    4/1/2015        1               0                    1
4    5/1/2015        1               0                    1
5    6/1/2015        1               0                    1
6    7/1/2015        1               0                    1
7    8/1/2015        2               0                    0
8    9/1/2015        2               0                    0
9   10/1/2015        2               0                    0
10  11/1/2015        2               0                    0
11  12/1/2015        2               0                    0
12  13/1/2015        2               0                    0
```

As pointed @Mohamed Thasin ah if necessary is possible groupby by week, but then get different output, because different [`week`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.week.html) numbers:

```
df['weeks'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.week

weeks = df.loc[df['Public_Holiday'].eq(1), 'weeks']
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = df['weeks'].isin(weeks).astype(int)
print (df)
         Date  WeekNum  Public_Holiday  weeks  Public_Holiday_Week
0    1/1/2015        1               1      1                    1
1    2/1/2015        1               0      1                    1
2    3/1/2015        1               0      1                    1
3    4/1/2015        1               0      1                    1
4    5/1/2015        1               0      2                    0
5    6/1/2015        1               0      2                    0
6    7/1/2015        1               0      2                    0
7    8/1/2015        2               0      2                    0
8    9/1/2015        2               0      2                    0
9   10/1/2015        2               0      2                    0
10  11/1/2015        2               0      2                    0
11  12/1/2015        2               0      3                    0
12  13/1/2015        2               0      3                    0
```

Comment: Nice answer but it would be great if you groupby with year and weeknum.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - sure, give me a sec

Answer (score 4):

#### `groupby` and `max`, with `map`:

```
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = df.WeekNum.map(df.groupby('WeekNum').Public_Holiday.max())
print(df)
         Date  WeekNum  Public_Holiday  Public_Holiday_Week
0    1/1/2015        1               1                    1
1    2/1/2015        1               0                    1
2    3/1/2015        1               0                    1
3    4/1/2015        1               0                    1
4    5/1/2015        1               0                    1
5    6/1/2015        1               0                    1
6    7/1/2015        1               0                    1
7    8/1/2015        2               0                    0
8    9/1/2015        2               0                    0
9   10/1/2015        2               0                    0
10  11/1/2015        2               0                    0
11  12/1/2015        2               0                    0
12  13/1/2015        2               0                    0
```

---

#### `groupby` and `transform`, with `max`

```
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = df.groupby('WeekNum').Public_Holiday.transform('max')
```

Thankfully, this will generalise nicely when grouping by month-year:

```
df['Public_Holiday_Week'] = (
     df.groupby(['WeekNum', df.Date.str.split('/', 1).str[1]])
      .Public_Holiday.transform('max')
)
print(df)
         Date  WeekNum  Public_Holiday  Public_Holiday_Week
0    1/1/2015        1               1                    1
1    2/1/2015        1               0                    1
2    3/1/2015        1               0                    1
3    4/1/2015        1               0                    1
4    5/1/2015        1               0                    1
5    6/1/2015        1               0                    1
6    7/1/2015        1               0                    1
7    8/1/2015        2               0                    0
8    9/1/2015        2               0                    0
9   10/1/2015        2               0                    0
10  11/1/2015        2               0                    0
11  12/1/2015        2               0                    0
12  13/1/2015        2               0                    0
```